# Convert WHERE Clause SUB query into LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have the following query:

```
select   b.StartDate,  b.MPName, a.DevicePrice, a.DeviceName
from DeviceDetails a
join MarketPrice b on b.DeviceCode = a.DeviceCode and b.DevicePCode = a.DevicePCode and ( b.prdCode is null or a.prdCode = b.prdCode )
WHERE 
b.CmdID = 1 
or ( b.CmdID = 2 and not exists ( select 1 from MarketPrice c where c.DeviceCode = b.DeviceCode and c.StartDate = b.StartDate and c.CmdID < 2 ) )
or ( b.CmdID = 3 and not exists ( select 1 from MarketPrice c where c.DeviceCode = b.DeviceCode and c.StartDate = b.StartDate and c.CmdID < 3 ) )
or ( b.CmdID = 4 and not exists ( select 1 from MarketPrice c where c.DeviceCode = b.DeviceCode and c.StartDate = b.StartDate and c.CmdID < 4 ) )
or ( b.CmdID = 5 and not exists ( select 1 from MarketPrice c where c.DeviceCode = b.DeviceCode and c.StartDate = b.StartDate and c.CmdID < 5 ) )
or ( b.CmdID = 6 and not exists ( select 1 from MarketPrice c where c.DeviceCode = b.DeviceCode and c.StartDate = b.StartDate and c.CmdID < 6 ) )
or ( b.CmdID = 7 and not exists ( select 1 from MarketPrice c where c.DeviceCode = b.DeviceCode and c.StartDate = b.StartDate and c.CmdID < 7 ) );
```

I want to convert the WHERE clause SUB Queries into a single LEFT join.

My try:

```
select   b.StartDate,  b.MPName, a.DevicePrice, a.DeviceName
from DeviceDetails a
join MarketPrice b on b.DeviceCode = a.DeviceCode and b.DevicePCode = a.DevicePCode and ( b.prdCode is null or a.prdCode = b.prdCode )
left join MarketPrice c on c.DeviceCode = b.DeviceCode and c.StartDate = b.StartDate
WHERE 
b.CmdID = 1 or ( b.CmdID = 2 and c.CmdID < 2) or ( b.CmdID = 3 and c.CmdID < 3)  or ( b.CmdID = 4 and c.CmdID < 4) 
or ( b.CmdID = 5 and c.CmdID < 5) or ( b.CmdID = 6 and c.CmdID < 6) or ( b.CmdID = 7 and c.CmdID < 7);
```

But records are not matching with base query.

Comment: Would this cover the whole shebang: WHERE 
not exists ( select 1 from MarketPrice c where c.DeviceCode = b.DeviceCode and c.StartDate = b.StartDate and c.CmdID < b.CMDID )

Comment: I might be completely misunderstanding but is this code looking for ID = 1, OR ID = 2 and doesn't already = 1, OR ID = 3 and doesn't already = 1 or 2? If so why does it matter if it is already included on a lower CmdID if you can just use MIN?

Comment: a, b and c are poor table aliases. Choose something that makes sense, like d (or dd) for DeviceDetails.

Answer (score 0):

There are few coding practices that I would improve in your original query, for example

- use meaningful aliases,
- when you have similar conditions, look for a way to unify into one rule: the NOT EXIST is the same formula all of them: `if > b.CmdID = [n] and not exists (... and c.CmdID < [n])` is shouting for a unified rule

As for your query, you can try placing a subquery in the `LEFT JOIN` to find the relevant MarketPrice rows.

Since you didn't post any sample data, I can't test it. but the query could look like something like this:

```
SELECT b.StartDate,  b.MPName, a.DevicePrice, a.DeviceName
FROM DeviceDetails a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT b.StartDate,  b.MPName, b.DeviceCode
    FROM MarketPrice b 
    WHERE b.CmdId = 1 
        OR NOT EXISTS (
            select 1 
            FROM MarketPrice c 
            WHERE c.DeviceCode = b.DeviceCode AND c.StartDate = b.StartDate AND c.CmdID < b.CmdID 
        )
) ON b.DeviceCode = a.DeviceCode AND b.DevicePCode = a.DevicePCode 
        AND ( b.prdCode IS NULL OR a.prdCode = b.prdCode 
        )
```